# Python Integrator: time column, data column

Tags: python, integrator

I have the following result:

```
Time Production
0 360
10 362
15 365
30 380
32 381
.. ..
```

The first column is the (simulation) time (not equi-distant); the second column is the production in kW.

Now i want to calculate the total production in kWh --> therefore i want to integrate the Production. Is there a straightforward way to do this in Python (numpy?)?

Thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use numpy trapizium rule to approximate,

```
import numpy as np

t = [0, 10, 15, 30, 32]
p = [360, 362, 365, 380, 381]

a = np.trapz(p,t)

print(a)
```

Comment: Probably shouldn't assign to a built-in.